# Need help in writing query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, database-administration

I am using below query to fetch the report for 10 different ids using union-all.Is there any way to reduce the query ?

```
SELECT 
sc.consentid,
CASE
    WHEN ue.userid IS NULL THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END ,
sc.firstname,
sc.lastname,
CASE
    WHEN SUM(time_on_page) > 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(time_on_page) / 60, 2)
    ELSE 'No videos watched'
END AS timeonpage,
'ID1' ,
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(article, video)) > 0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(article, video))
    ELSE 'no video in list watched'
END AS countvideoswatched
FROM
studentconsent AS sc
    LEFT JOIN
useremails AS ue USING (email)
    LEFT JOIN
masterstats_innodb AS m ON ue.userid = m.user_id
WHERE
(sc.email LIKE '%.it'
    AND (sc.consentid IS NOT NULL
    AND m.id IS NULL)
    OR (m.id IS NOT NULL
    AND m.timestamp >= '2020-12-01'
    AND (video IN (SELECT 
        objectid
    FROM
        playlists
            JOIN
        playlisttoobjects USING (playlistid)
    WHERE
        unique_id = 'ID1'
            AND objecttype = 'article'))))
GROUP BY sc.consentid
union all (query2 with differentid)....so on
```

Here I need to use union-all command to combine all 10 select queries with different id.Any way to reduce it?

Comment: I'm guessing that `unique_id` is the column you want to filter on?  If so, just use `unique_id in ('A','B',...)`.

Comment: but there is case condition with different unique_id @Andrew

Comment: Below I am using case to display unique_id,if i use in then it will display same unique_id for all rows                                                                                           
         `CASE
    WHEN SUM(time_on_page) > 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(time_on_page) / 60, 2)
    ELSE 'No videos watched'
END AS timeonpage,
'ID1' ,`

Comment: This is an overly complicated query to ask for help on. You aren't even qualifying unique_id in your query, so I have no idea what table it's coming from.  An `IN` clause is the basic answer to your question.

Comment: unique_id is coming from playlists table @Andrew